# setting properties and delegates -- when to use self?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, protocols

I'm working through the `NSXMLParser` sample code and I have a couple of questions about how delegates and properties are set, particularly in the `AppDelegate`.

In the interface, the `AppDelegate` is declared to follow the `NSXMLParserDelegate protocol`, but it doesn't seem to implement any of the protocol methods or to set itself as the delegate at any point. These seem to be in the `ParseOperation` class. Is this just a typo?

```
@interface SeismicXMLAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    RootViewController *rootViewController;

@private
    // for downloading the xml data
    NSURLConnection *earthquakeFeedConnection;
    NSMutableData *earthquakeData;

    NSOperationQueue *parseQueue;
}
```

The interface also declares some private properties. These are defined again in an interface extension in the .m file.

```
@interface SeismicXMLAppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *earthquakeFeedConnection;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *earthquakeData;    // the data returned from the NSURLConnection
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOperationQueue *parseQueue;     // the queue that manages our NSOperation for parsing earthquake data

- (void)addEarthquakesToList:(NSArray *)earthquakes;
- (void)handleError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

OK, I think I understand that this means other classes can't access these properties, and that seems like a really good thing in this case. Here's the mystery - In the implementation of -`applicationDidFinishLaunching:` the two properties are defined using different notations.

```
self.earthquakeFeedConnection =
[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:earthquakeURLRequest delegate:self] autorelease];
```

vs

```
parseQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
```

Why is one assigned using `self.propertyName =` and the other with `propertyName =` ? I know that both `parseQueue` and `earthquakeFeedConnection` end up with retain counts of 1, with the difference that `earthquakeFeedConnection` is part of the `autorelease pool` and will be released automatically whereas we'll have to release `parseQueue` later because of the use of `+new` and not calling `autorelease`.

The memory considerations don't explain the use of self. Is there another difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alloc` and `new` return objects which are retained once. `init` have no effect on memory-management and `autorelease` will release that object *later* once.

if you write `self.myProperty = ...` then the `synthesized` setter is called which behaves like you defined in the according property `nonatomic, retain`. The `nonatomic` means that the getter and setter are not threadsafe (but fast). `retain` means in this case that the setter will release the old object and will retain the new object. if you wrote `assign` instead of `retain` the setter would just assign the pointer and wouldn't call release or retain on the affected objects.

The goal in your example is to create two objects which are retained once.
Example1:

```
self.earthquakeFeedConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:earthquakeURLRequest delegate:self] autorelease];
```

- after  alloc: retainCount: 1
- after autorelease: retainCount: 1-1  (minus one means: released later)
- after calling the setter: retainCount: 2-1

Exmaple 2:

`parseQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];`

- after new: retainCount: 1

So in the end both cases result in the same. you could also write

```
earthquakeFeedConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:earthquakeURLRequest delegate:self];
```

The setter-solution looks more complicated but there are some side-effects. If you notice later that you need special behaviour inside either the getter or setter (for instance: triggering some other methods or do some value-checking: NSString which only should contains eMail-Addresses) then you only have to overwrite the getter or setter. If you dont use `self.myProp = ...` then you have to search for usage and have to change that code-snippet as well.

The delegate-stuff: yes, you are right: normally you have to (or should) list alle implemented protocols in the interface-definition but the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` is an exception. I dont know why (I dont find the implementation-point in `NSObject`-class-reference) but every `NSObject` implements that delegate already. So as a result you dont have to mention that your class is implementing that delegate.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the NSURLConnection protocol methods, but what about NSXMLParser delegate methods? It doesn't implement _any_. I'll edit my post, because I think I do understand the retain count implications. But this is a simple sample app. There's no custom implementation of the setters and getters. So why is the parseQueue assigned without the use of self.parseQueue?

Comment: I guess it is just a coding-style of the author (or just a copy-paste-fragment). You can also write `self.parseQueue = [[NSOperationQueue new] autorelease];`.  If he dont implement the `NSXMLParserDelegate` then it is unnecessary. You say it is an `NSXMLParser-Tutorial`, maybe the actual parse-algorithm is out-sourced to another file and the author just forgot the remove that protocol-implementation. That is the problem if a protocol only contains optional implementations... Can you post the link to that tutorial?

Comment: It's sample code from Apple. You can find it at developer.apple.com
<a href=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html title="SeismicXML"</a>. I got to it from the class documentation on NSOperations.

Comment: yap, I took a look at that document. It seems that the `NSXMLParserDelegate` in the AppDelegate is just a leftover (it shouldn't be there). It happens no warning or error at compile-time because the methods of `NSXMLParser` are all optional. The alloc-init vs. new thing: I think it is just a coding-style of the author: he loves to use new without calling the setter except he wants to use an `initWith...`-method: then he also uses the setter. It should be really just a reflect the mood of the author or just the author's coding-style...

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:**
Thomas's answer does confirm the delegate protocol mystery. The declaration is, as I suggested originally, just a typo. So I'm not missing the boat, which is nice, so I'm accepting his answer.

The answer about the use of -alloc, -init vs +new is less satisfying. The phrase 'just a coding style' seems to dismiss something important, so I've come up with my own analysis.  Basically, I think this is a defensive element of the authors style: this approach makes no assumptions about the initialized object.

**verbose=N**
Combining +new and a custom setter could lead to trouble. If the custom implementation of the setter assumes that the initialized object has a particular state (such as something that might have been done in a custom -init method), there could be bad effects. Avoid any conflicts by making no assumptions about the object. Make sure that a custom setter is not called unless the customization has clearly been done. Thus, safely call [self setPropCustom] = [[PropClass alloc] initWithCustomization], and avoid calling [self setPropCustom] on [[PropClass alloc] init]. Since -init is often overriden, get a bare minimum object by +new instead of -alloc,-init.

**vervose=Y**
I'm a noobie of a sort. I have background in getting things done, but very little in doing it elegantly or in a CS fashion. So I'm interested in coding styles. Why might the author 'love' to do it that a particular way? It she's experienced, I really doubt it's just a 'mood'.

There's a lot of discussion of coding style at [Wil Shipley's blog](http://blog.wilshipley.com/), particularly the 'Pimp my code' series, which is a sort of gem. It includes a rather detailed discussion of +new vs -alloc,-init.  I'll quote one of the [comments](http://blog.wilshipley.com/2005/08/pimp-my-code-part-4-returning-late-to.html):

corwin said...

> [edited] Code is a craft. It's inexact. Writing code that follows everyone
>   else's style is like writing poetry in the same meter and pattern as
>   everyone else. Think a little, realize that every little quirk your
>   code imparts is a little part of you, and get over making it
>   "perfect". Read others' code like you would poetry- take inspiration
>   from it, learn from it, sometimes imitate it, but never take it as a
>   personal affront.
>
> At the end of the day, you should ask yourself: Did the code I write
>   make art? Will it make a user's life easier? Did it make me feel good? If you can answer those questions yes, you're OK. All else is void.
>   August 25, 2005 12:08 AM

So, in this vein, what can I learn from the coding style in NSXMLParser? What inspiration can I get out of it? Well…

The point of having a coding style is to give yourself extra information in the way that you choose to do something, and to use consistent patterns to avoid known pitfalls.  There are generally multiple ways of achieving a desired result. Allocating memory is something at programmers do continuously. It gets called so much that it helps to be consistent in how you go about it. Gee, if I was consistent about where I put the baby's shoes, I wouldn't have to hunt around for 10 minutes every morning. Consistency is a shortcut, and a coding style gives your code consistency.

Poetry is about multiple meanings. It's about not just invoking a word, but invoking an emotion or a sensation at the same time. 
… so juicy and so sweet.

So developing a coding style is developing a concise and consistent means of communicating with another programmer or with your future self. You shouldn't have to ask 'what was I doing here'. It should be part of your coding style.

So back to NSXMLParser. According to Thomas, this author *'loves to use new without calling the setter except he wants to use an `initWith...`-method: then he also uses the setter.'* (thomas, Oct 4). What I want to know is *why* did the author choose this convention as part of his coding style? What is the sense of it?

Of course, I wouldn't be writing this except that I think I understand.

When you write a class, you can override -init, but you don't override +new. When you write a class, you may override the synthesized setters and getters -setProperty and -property.

By consistently assigning the property directly when using +new, the author uses syntax to emphasize that this is a 'nude' object. Empty. The barest minimum. Then he makes sure to assign it without calling the setter. This seems like a good idea. After all, **combining +new and a custom setter could lead to trouble if the custom implementation of the setter assumed anything about the state of the initialized object (such as something that might have been done in the custom -init method).Better to avoid the problem.** Ah. There it is. The answer I was looking for.

So what can I, in my ragged noobie state take from this 'coding style'. Hmmm…
that one will have to stew for a while. Take number 1:

1. Calling `+new` and avoiding any custom setters is defensive coding.
2. Customizing `-init` and the default setters should be done with
   care.
3. If a custom `-init` method is desired, it might be better to rename
   it `-initWithDefaults` or something.   On the other hand, if you
   consistently use `+new` with assignment without calling `self`, then you
   can probably get away with more customization, but you will have to
   be consistent.

I am old enough to know for a fact that I am not consistent. The shoe hunt occurs at least once a week, despite some effort on my part. So I need a coding style that is defensive. To this end, I should do both:  1) develop a love of +new with direct assignment when a bare object is desired and 2) try to avoid overriding the default implementations of init and the synthesized setters and getters.

As Thomas says:

> 'there are some side-effects. If you notice later that you need
>   special behaviour inside either the getter or setter (for instance:
>   triggering some other methods or do some value-checking: NSString
>   which only should contains eMail-Addresses) then you only have to
>   overwrite the getter or setter. If you dont use self.myProp = ... then
>   you have to search for usage and have to change that code-snippet as
>   well.'

Fair enough. If I avoid customizing the setters and getters, I end up having to make sure that my extra behavior occurs somewhere else. But, actually, I already tend to do that by implementing things like 
    -changeLocationTo:(CLLocation *)aPlace inTimeZone:(NSTimeZone *)timeZone'. 
The checking goes in there and it's pretty obvious what it does from the naming, and it's existence reminds me that when I change `aPlace`, I also want to make sure I check its `timeZone`. I call the default `self.setTimeZone` and `self.setAPlace` from there, and do any cleanup. 
The beginnings of a style. But it probably has some downsides...